# Здравствуйте, товарищи, начал изучать базы данных, установил PostgreSQL 12. После долгого запуска pgAdmin4 выскакивает ошибка

Tags: база-данных, sql-server, postgresql, pgadmin4

товарищи, начал изучать базы данных, установил PostgreSQL 12. При запуске появляется небольшое окошко с надписью pgAdmin 4 и после долгого ожидания выскакивает ошибка "the application server could not be contacted"
Пробовал запускать pgAdmin4 от имени админа, файрволлу доступ разрешил, добавлял путь в переменные окружения, очищал папку с временными файлами, но всё это не помогло мне. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как быть в этой ситуации?

Comment: Службу postgres пробовали перезапускать? Если не поможет зайдите в AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin, удалите папку pgAdmin и запустите pgAdmin заново.

Comment: @FredPerry , а как перезапустить службу postgres?

Comment: если у вас WIndows 10, зайдите в службы, найдите postgresql-x64-12 (у меня называется так) и перезапустите. Но второй способ с удалением папки более действенный.

Comment: @FredPerry , с удалением папки пробовал, не принесло результата и перезапуск postgres тоже не помог. А возможно ли в интернете отыскать рабочую сборку с pgAdmin3? Я как то его скачивал, он успешно открывался, но там не было postgreSQL

Comment: Можно с оф. сайта, postgres с pgadmin4: https://www.postgresql.org/download/ и отдельно версия pgadmin на выбор: https://www.pgadmin.org/download/

Comment: @FredPerry , то есть просто установить postgreSQL с pgAdmin4 и вдобавок поставить pgAdmin3? А надо манипуляции с путями проводить?Допустим, pgAdmin3  в определенную папку ставить или еще что - то в этом духе?Так же слышал, что pgAdmin3 работает только с postgreSQL версий от 8.4 до 9.3